# Search functionality with retrofit and mvvm android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I have an android application which I use MVVM and Retrofit in. 
and I want to apply search in this application I have an api for search and api return result correctly via post man but when I try to build it in android I get confused because I get wrong results.
this is my code 
***SearchRepo.java***

```
public class SearchRepo {
    private Application application;
    private ApiService apiService;

    public SearchRepo(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        this.apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL)
                .create(ApiService.class);
    }

    public void SearchForKeyWord(String lang, String keyword, int perPage,
                                 SearchRepositoryCallBack<ProductModel> callBack) {
        apiService.search(lang,keyword,perPage)
                .enqueue(new Callback<ProductModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ProductModel> call, Response<ProductModel> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            callBack.onSuccess(response.body());
                        } else {
                            callBack.onFailure("Error : "+response.code());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ProductModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        callBack.onFailure("Error : "+t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    public interface SearchRepositoryCallBack<T> {
        void onSuccess(T post);
        void onFailure(String error);
    }
}
```

***SearchViewModel.java***

```
public class SearchViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private SearchRepo search;
    private MutableLiveData<ProductModel> searchResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public SearchViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.search = new SearchRepo(application);
    }

    public void searchProducts(String lang,String keyword,int perPage) {
        search.SearchForKeyWord(lang, keyword, perPage, new SearchRepo.SearchRepositoryCallBack<ProductModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ProductModel post) {
                searchResult.postValue(post);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String error) {
                Log.e(APITAG,error);
            }
        });
    }

    public LiveData<ProductModel> getSearchResult() {
        return searchResult;
    }
}
```

***search method in searchFragment.java***

```
private void search(String lang, String keyword, int perPage) {
        productViewModel.searchProduct(lang,keyword,perPage);
        productViewModel.getResultList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ProductModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ProductModel productModel) {
                List<Product> mlist = productModel.getData();
                for (int i=0;i<mlist.size();i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("My List "+mlist.size());
                    System.out.println("My List "+mlist.get(i).getName());
                }
                System.out.println("=====================================");
            }
        });
    }
```

when I type a text to search I get a correct result, but if I removed the word and try to write another one I get old result and correct result, number of result is exponential. 
***example***

```
1
======
input -> m
expected -> "moon" , "mine"
actual output -> "moon" , "mine"
=====================
2
======
input -> a
expected -> "apple" , "alpha"
actual output -> "moon" , "mine" , "apple" , "alpha" , "apple" , "alpha"
====================
3
======
input -> l
expected -> "locus" , "lord"
actual output -> "apple" , "alpha" , "apple" , "alpha" , "locus" , "lord" , "locus" , "lord"
```

so what is the problem and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new observer every time you call `search(String lang, String keyword, int perPage)` in your fragment, So the first time you call the search function you have one observer, in the second time you have two observers and so on. all of them are alive and work until the fragment die so they print new data which `searchResult` mutableLiveData emits.

You must have only one observer to observe your `searchResult` mutable live data, therefore put this piece of code into your `onCreateView()` or any other function which call once in the whole lifecycle of your fragment.

```java
productViewModel.getResultList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<ProductModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ProductModel productModel) {
                List<Product> mlist = productModel.getData();
                for (int i=0;i<mlist.size();i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println("My List "+mlist.size());
                    System.out.println("My List "+mlist.get(i).getName());
                }
                System.out.println("=====================================");
            }
        });
```

and to search new strings just use below code:

```java
productViewModel.searchProduct(lang,keyword,perPage);
```

don't create new observer to get new result, new results will be accessible on your previous observer which you created in your `onCreateView()`.